# Neo4j UnitTest and APOC

Tags: java, junit, neo4j

I am successfully running a few Unit-Tests with neo4js in memory test server.

Currently I am writing a few functions that make use of APOC "Awesome Procedures On Cypher", which works fine on the local installation, but testing with JUnit results  in a `org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException`:

> "There is no procedure with the name `apoc.index.nodes` registered for
>   this database instance."

I have to use neo4js in-memory test server for testing. My question is how do I properly use APOC with it?

Comment: Did you register the procedure for the test server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use neo4j-harness as described in the docs to test with an in-memory Neo4j server, and it's rules have a method to register functions and procedures.

See here: https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#_writing_integration_tests

Comment: That link does not contain any info on integration tests, unfortunately. Any idea where to find that?